# Loading image not displaying in Google Chrome

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, cross-browser

I need to display a progress bar until upload and display images from my website. For that I chose progress bar [from here](https://www.freshdesignweb.com/jquery-css3-loading-progress-bar/).

I used below code in my `scripts.js` file:

```js
div = $('<div class="loader-fb"/>');
div.appendTo('.selected_album_inner');
```

```css
.loader-fb {
    top: calc(50% - 5px);
    left: calc(50% - 5px);
    position: absolute !important;
}
/* Demo specific styles end */
    
/* Loader with three blocks */
.loader-fb, .loader-fb:before, .loader-fb:after {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
    width: 20px;
    height: 50px;
    background-color: rgba(215,230,240,0.9);
    border: 1px solid rgb(215,230,240);
    z-index: 100000;
    content: ' ';
    margin-left: -5px;
    margin-right: -9px;
}
.loader-fb:before {
    top: -11px;
    left: -100%;
    animation: loading-fb .8s cubic-bezier(.4,.5,.6,1) infinite;
}
.loader-fb {
    animation: loading-fb-main .8s cubic-bezier(.4,.5,.6,1) .2s infinite;
}
.loader-fb:after {
    top: -11px;
    right: -100%;
    margin-top: 50%;
    animation: loading-fb .8s cubic-bezier(.4,.5,.6,1) .4s infinite;
}
@keyframes loading-fb {
    from {
        transform: scaleY(1.4);
        background-color: rgba(55,114,171,0.9);
        border: 1px solid rgb(55,114,171);
    }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="selected_album_inner">
```

The progress bar is only displaying in mozilla firefox, but not in chrome. Any idea?

Comment: That work for me in chrome : http://jsfiddle.net/qYdwR/2605/

Comment: Can we see this live?